# develop django app that support multiple clients simultaneously just like search engines?

Tags: python, django, web-crawler

I'm developing a web crawler in python using Django framework. i want it to work like a web-app. Means if I open in two different browser tabs, they should work individually, each having its own data (crawled + queued links). Both of them should start crawling from separate URL and continue their work.

currently i have designed very simple version of it. it is working in one tab, does not work in another browser tab. I have even tried opening a new window of chrome but same results.

I'm not sure what feature or library i should use for that purpose. can somebody help me?

Comment: Did you look at [the documentation for sessions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/sessions/)? This [Create a Session in Django](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2293291/create-a-session-in-django) question might also be helpful.

Comment: Unless you are writing the Django app as a learning exercise I'd use something more suited to the task, such as scrapy: https://scrapy.org

Answer (score 1):

You can pass some key in the URL:

```
URL PATTER<your_domain>/crowled/<P>
```

you can open each URL in different TAB

```
TAB1: <your_domain>/crowled/abcd
TAB2: <your_domain>/crowled/xyz
```

OR you can send some key on request.GET

Answer (score 1):

I would create default page for your app which is a form to accept one or more URLs to crawl.

When the 'submit' button is pressed the list of URLs is stored in the database and a background process, using something such as [celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/), works through the queue of URLs.

You don't say anything about how the results of the crawl are to be stored/presented, so I'm assuming you just want to kickstart the crawl and the pages are stored in some way by the code crawling the sites - with no response sent to the web page.