# How can send variable data from one function to another function in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

Is this possible to send variable data of one function into another function in Django?
Note:- both functions received request as an argument and render in return

for example:-
in views.py

```
def func1(request):
     user = 'username'
     email = 'email'
     context = {'user':user,'email':email}
     render return(request,'template.html', ,context)

def func2(request):
      #want to received user and email value in this function
     render return(request,'template.html')
```

Comment: A wild guess would be, that what you are looking for is Sessions https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2293291/create-a-session-in-django

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it like this:

```
def func1(request):
     user = 'username'
     email = 'email'
     context = {'user':user,'email':email}
     func2(request,user)
     render return(request,'template.html', ,context)

def func2(request,user):
      #want to received user and email value in this function
     render return(request,'template.html')
```

I am not sure why you want to do this because you cant render both templates at the same time but what you could do is use one function on post request and the other on a get request.

If you want func2 to sometimes run without a user you can make it optional. I hope I understood the question right and could help you!