# Send user to the page they requested before Signing in with google, after they sign in with google

Tags: django, google-logging

I have a movie quiz app https://www.quizsocial.xyz/, where users can search for a trending movie and take a quiz about the movie’s story, so when they land on the homepage, they search for their movie, they click start quiz, they agree to the rules, they
select how many questions they want to attempt

and then they have to sign in with google or create an account, now if they create an account through us, their requested quiz will start automatically once they sign in, but when they do the same thing with google log in, they are redirected to the homepage.

Where they have to search for the quiz again, agree to the rules, select how many questions they want to attempt. This may annoy some users and lead them to leave the website and never come back.

My question is how do I retrieve their data before they signed up with google and then send them to the exact page they requested after they sign in with google.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution would be to use Django sessions to store their selections

Here is an old resource for that.
[Create a Session in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2293291/create-a-session-in-django)

**Edit. - this part assumes you are using oath2* which if you are not may not apply, but sessions could still be a possible solution***
When using Google to authenticate, they require a redirect uri "callback" function.

I would assume you already have this function built out. In this function, once a user is successfully logged in, you can redirect the user anywhere you want.  Use the information you stored in the session to build your new redirect URL.